# Tomcat Error while running struts2 web application

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2

When I try to run simple struts2 web application server is giving:

> The origin server did not find a current representation for the target
>   resource  or is not willing to disclose that one exists

I have tried all the solutions provided like

1.Building  application manually

2.Changing the build Path to deployment assembly

3.Checking the server.xml file

4.Changing the workspace directory

Also I have uninstalled and reinstalled tomcat but the issue still persists.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fONF5.png)

This is POM.XML

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.prasad.webapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyApplication</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>MyApplication Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.14.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>MyApplication</finalName>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.0</version>

    </plugin>
    <plugin>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>9.4.0.M0</version>
  </plugin>

    </plugins>

  </build>
</project>
```

TutorialAction.java

```
package org.java.action;

public class TutorialAction {

    String language;

    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    public String execute() {

        if(getLanguage().equals("Java")) {

        return "success";
        }

        else {
            return "failure";
        }
    }

}
```

Failure.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Failure Page</title>
</head>
<body>
Sorryyyy...!!!!!!!!!!!!
</body>
</html>
```

success.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Success Page</title>
</head>
<body>
Struts2 in Java
</body>
</html>
```

struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts  
Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">  

<struts>

<package name="default" extends="struts-default">

<action name="getTutorial"  class="org.java.action.TutorialAction">

<result name="success">success.jsp</result>
<result name="failure">failure.jsp</result>
</action>


</package>


</struts>
```

Log4j.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.opensymphony.xwork2" level="debug"/>
        <Logger name="org.apache.struts2" level="debug"/>
        <Root level="warn">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Basic Struts2</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: The error message might be useful sometimes but it useless without looking in the code.

Comment: All the code is added

Comment: You should post only relevant code. Describe the steps to reproduce your problem.

Comment: When I run  the application on the server the starting page itself is error which I posted above

Comment: Which is the starting page?